# SQL query, return randomly ordered rows with limits, possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am thinking of returning a randomly ordered `SQL` response where the results are mixed up randomly, with a limit. 
The thing is I need All the rows back, basically divided into groups (chunks of rows). I hope I am clear.

For example, from table A:

```
ID   |   NAME    |   PROFESSION
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1    |  Jack     |   Carpenter
2    |  Rob      |   Manager
3    |  Phil     |   Driver
4    |  Mary     |   Cook
5    |  Tim      |   Postman
6    |  Bob      |   Programmer
```

The query would return something like this:

With a limit of 0,2:

```
6    |  Bob      |   Programmer
4    |  Mary     |   Cook
```

With a limit of 2,2:

```
1    |  Jack     |   Carpenter
5    |  Tim      |   Postman
```

With a limit of 4,2:

```
3    |  Phil     |   Driver
2    |  Rob      |   Manager
```

Note: `all the table rows were returned`. In my page I need to have a `<<` `>>` buttons that will show the user the needed "group"s of data. 
How do I go about writing such a query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better name for your explained problem would be *randomly shuffled records*. That is true that the order is random but since the order needs to be remembered, you have no choice but to save it in a column. You can do this by saving a randomly populated field and ordering your records based on that. This way you have ordered your records in no specific order while the order is remembered for future select queries. And whenever you got tired of the order, you can update the mentioned field with new randomly generated values to shuffle them again. This is the technique used by players to shuffle a playlist without replaying a song twice.

[EDIT]

While the first given solution stands as the general answer, there's a hack you can use in MySQL to randomly order records. In this way, all you need to store for remembering an order is its seed.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY RAND(s);
```

For instance, if you want each user see the records in some different randomly ordered, you can use their user_id as the seed. This way the order each user will ever see the records in, will remain the same while it is random and different from other users.

Comment: I'd say this would require a new table for each search a user commits ?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things here:

1. If the data in the table is huge, add a column that tells the group to which a row belongs. When the user clicks on >> or << buttons, get the rows for that particular group.
2. If you are dealing with small amount of data, you could do this in the code itself.

Comment: The result has to be randomized, so adding columns won't make it randomized. And yes, big amount of data

Comment: What is the criteria based on which data is to be returned from database? Is totally random set of rows or is their any rule that decides data to return?

Comment: Exactly. Random order. Like on youtube when you shuffle? a random order is decided upon at first, and then you only get sections of it

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ORDER BY RAND()` then you will have to flag selected records somewhere which is no advisable.

You can use some intelligent algorithm with combination of `total_pages` and `ID` e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM  my_table
ORDER BY MOD(ID, total_pages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to the table called something like *random_col*

Then each time you need to randomise the table you run

```
UPDATE table SET random_col = RAND()
```

And now each time you want to retrieve results you run a normal select

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY random_col ASC LIMIT x,y
```

And the results will appear in the same order until you randomise them again by running the 'UPDATE'

Comment: That's a good idea providing there is only one user. If two users use this, it would mix the results for both

Comment: btw, although very minor chance, two cols can have the same random number